# WPF application (development environment ) which creates a new WPF app

Tags: c#, wpf, development-environment

I'm interested in creating a development environment  in WPF which can aid non-programmers(like parents) to write simple programs in C# for  children.  So, I want to make a WPF application  (development environment  ) which creates a new WPF app. It's impossible, right?

Comment: I do'nt agree Nothing is impossible.

Comment: i dont think so that it is impossible but it is time taking. And it depends on to what level you are developing the app

Comment: @ethicallogics I'd like to see your solution to the Halting problem then.

Comment: @ethicallogics but doing nothing is really hard to do. I've never quite done it.

Comment: @svick lol thanks for pulling the leg. like kashmiri legion said its not impossible but it will require a great big team/Company to create such application and Creates its Configuration system which is fully configurable and parents can play with it.

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple way to prove that doing so is not impossible: finding some existing application that can create new WPF applications. But that's exactly what Visual Studio does.

So, no, it's *not* impossible.

If you want to know whether doing that would be *easy*, that's completely different question.

Comment: In fact starting with a visual studio extension is probably a good way to achieve the goal, since there would be a whole lot VS would do for you.

Comment: But the OP is "creating a development environment in (not for) WPF" and Visual Studio is not a WPF application.  Just messing with you svick.  You have answered some of my questions.

Comment: @Blam You're right that it's not really relevant, but VS 2010 *was* written in WPF.